# token_exchange_failed when I try to login in react-native with IdentityServer4

Tags: react-native, identityserver4

I need to create Mobile client for my app. And I need to authenticate/authorize users. 
I'm new in Mobile development, so I decided to use react-native because I have some experience with react.

I used the following stack:

- react-native (v0.66.4)
- react-native-app-auth (v6.4.0)
- IdentityServer4

I have the following Client configuration in IdentityServer4

```
new Client
{
    RequireConsent = false,

    ClientId = "28BDF82E-4443-4097-9430-C44471398728",
    ClientName = "Mobile Client",
    RequireClientSecret = false,

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

    RedirectUris =
    {
        "io.identityserver.demo:/oauthredirect"
    },

    RequirePkce = true,
    AllowedScopes = {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
    },

    AllowOfflineAccess = true
}
```

When user tries to authenticate from Mobile App

```
const configs = {
  clientId: '28BDF82E-4443-4097-9430-C44471398728',
  redirectUrl: 'io.identityserver.demo:/oauthredirect',
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access'],
  serviceConfiguration: {
    authorizationEndpoint: 'https://localhost:5101/connect/authorize',
    tokenEndpoint: 'https://localhost:5101/connect/token',
    revocationEndpoint: 'https://localhost:5101/connect/revoke',
  },
};

const newAuthState = await authorize(configs);
```

He is redirected to the log-in page of Identity Server. After user enters credentials, he is redirected back to the mobile app, but then he gets this error:

```
{
    "nativeStackAndroid": [
        {
            "methodName": "doInBackground",
            "lineNumber": 636,
            "file": "AuthorizationService.java",
            "class": "net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService$TokenRequestTask"
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doInBackground",
            "lineNumber": 564,
            "file": "AuthorizationService.java",
            "class": "net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService$TokenRequestTask"
        },
        {
            "methodName": "call",
            "lineNumber": 394,
            "file": "AsyncTask.java",
            "class": "android.os.AsyncTask$3"
        },
        {
            "methodName": "run",
            "lineNumber": 266,
            "file": "FutureTask.java",
            "class": "java.util.concurrent.FutureTask"
        },
        {
            "methodName": "run",
            "lineNumber": 305,
            "file": "AsyncTask.java",
            "class": "android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1"
        },
        {
            "methodName": "runWorker",
            "lineNumber": 1167,
            "file": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
            "class": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor"
        },
        {
            "methodName": "run",
            "lineNumber": 641,
            "file": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
            "class": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker"
        },
        {
            "methodName": "run",
            "lineNumber": 923,
            "file": "Thread.java",
            "class": "java.lang.Thread"
        }
    ],
    "userInfo": null,
    "message": "Network error",
    "code": "token_exchange_failed",
    "line": 2552,
    "column": 45,
    "sourceURL": "http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mobileclient&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true"
}
```

Did anyone have this error and can anyone help me to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this issue?